# xpath exclude element and all its children by parent attribute containing a value

Tags: html, dom, xpath, css-selectors

Example of a markup:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <p>
        <moredepth>
            <...>
                <span class="image-container float_right">
                    <div class="some_element">
                        image1
                    </div>
                    <p>do not need this</p>
                </span>
                <div class="image-container float_right">
                    image2
                </div>
                <p>text1</p>
                <li>text2</li>
            </...>
        </moredepth>
    </p>
</div>
```

Worst part is that depth of "image-container" can be on any level.

Xpath I try to use:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'post-content')]//*[not(contains(@class, 'image-container'))]
```

What Xpath should I use to be able to exclude "some_element" and any other children of "image-container" of any depth and an "image-container" element itself?

Output in this example should be:

```
<p>
    <moredepth>
        <...>

            <p>text1</p>
            <li>text2</li>
        </...>
    </moredepth>
</p>
```

P.S. Is it possible to make such a selection using CSS?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the output you expect (post this HTML).

Comment: Why should the outer `p` and `moredepth` elements not be selected? Do you only want children of `moredepth`?

Comment: I need to select p and moredepth. But I need to exclude class that contains 'image-container' and all its child element

Comment: @MathiasMüller editted the question for the output markup again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath does not allow manipulating a fragment of XML once it is returned to you by a path expression. So, you cannot select `moredepth`:

```
//moredepth
```

without getting as a result *all* of this element node, including all descendant nodes that you'd like to exclude:

```
<moredepth>
<span class="image-container float_right">
<div class="some_element">
image1
</div>
<p>do not need this</p>
</span>
<div class="image-container float_right">
image2
</div>
<p>text1</p>
<li>text2</li>
</moredepth>
```

What you can do is only select the child nodes of `moredepth`:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'post-content')]/p/moredepth/*[not(contains(@class,'image-container'))]
```

which will yield (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
<p>text1</p>
-----------------------
<li>text2</li>
```

Comment: Although, this answer does not solve my problem, it is correct. You cannot do this with XPath. I ended up writing my custom script for this task.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the Kaysian method for obtaining the intersection of a set. You have two sets:

A: The elements which descend from `//div[contains(@class, 'post-content')]`, excluding the current element (since you don't want the root `div`):

```
//*[ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'post-content')]]
```

B: The elements which descend from `//*[not(contains(@class, 'image-container'))]`, including the current element (since you want to exclude the entire tree, including the `div` and `span`):

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, 'image-container')])]
```

The intersection of those two sets is the solution to your problem. The formula of the Kaysian method is: `A [ count(. | B) = count(B) ]`. Applying that to your problem, the result you need is:

```
//*[ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'post-content')]]
   [ count(. | //*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, 'image-container')])])
     = 
     count(//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, 'image-container')])]) ]
```

This will select the following elements from your example code:

```
/div/p
/div/p/moredepth
/div/p/moredepth/...
/div/p/moredepth/.../p
/div/p/moredepth/.../li
```

excluding the `span` and the `div` that match the unwanted class, and its descendants.

You can then add extra steps to the expression to filter out exactly which text or nodes you need.

Comment: Great! That `not(ancestor-or-self::*)` thing worked. In case anyone needs it, I needed all `ul` elements of a class `link-list` that did not have `aside` ancestor, so I wrote `"//ul[contains(@class, 'link-list') and not(ancestor-or-self::aside)]"`.